# how to make http port to open after application startup in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

By default in tomcat the http port opens as soon as the application is started. This causes many requests to timeout. How to make http port open after application startup on tomcat when the servlet loading is complete?

Comment: Personally I would not add any new server instance to my load balancer until it's fully initialized, then passes an internal smoke test.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Start-connectors-after-deployment-of-all-webapps-have-been-completed-td2005769.html),

> have a look at the bindOnInit parameter on the connector http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: I checked by setting bindOnInit value but still this is not working. Any ideas regarding what could be the possible reason for this. I read many posts on this. People are saying that this depends on the way the app has been built, but I am not getting enough idea from the responses.

Comment: Also is there a way I can check the values which are actually getting picked up by the tomcat. I have set this attribute value in the Connector xml tag.

Comment: Also I ran the same application with jetty server. There I am not getting this issue. Only tomcat is binding the port because of which this happening. Can some one please help in this problem.

Comment: Ok I found a reason for this. It is because of tomcat 6. There is no parameter for tomcat6.

Comment: Ah, yeah the setting I mentioned is only on Tomcat 7.