# How does container handle servlet request before load-on-startup?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to guarantee the order of the init method calls on a couple of servlets. My thought is to specify a load-on-startup value of 1 for the first servlet I want to initialize and a value of 2 for the load-on-startup value of the second servlet I want to initialize.

My question is what happens if I get a request for servlet 2 before the servlet 1 initialization completes?

Hi Jarrod,
I don't believe my question was a duplicate.
Thanks, Charlie

Comment: Clarification please: Where does the answered question above indicate no requests to any servlet with load-on-startup are serviced until the completion of load-on-startup for all servlets with load-on-startup?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A request will not be handled by a web application before the web application has started up. If you specify a non-negative `load-on-startup` value, it means that the servlet `init()` method invocation will occur during the web application startup. As a result, such a servlet will not handle any request until its `init()` method has finished.

So servlet container will call `init()` on servlets with non-negative `load-on-startup` (in order) and only then it will allow them to handle requests.

Tomcat 7 with default configuration delays requests received during the application startup (at least, in my case).

More information on Tomcat specifics in the answer to [Prevent Tomcat from caching request during starup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001473/prevent-tomcat-from-caching-request-during-starup)

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question. A request can't sneak in and trigger an init out of order when load-on-startup is specified.

Comment: Please accept the answer :)